# jQuery is(':visible') is(':hidden') not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this script below, I set an element to visible or hidden as you'll can see. However, once .closeAdd is shown it will not hide if the script comes to the second part in the if statement. I've noticed that jQuery sets it to `display:block` when it uses show(). Any idea how I can set this right?

```
if(type === 'user' && action === 'add') {
    if($('.closeAdd').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.closeAdd').show();
    }
} else { //If it's visible and it comes to this part, it will not hide...
    if($('.closeAdd').is(':visible')) {
        $('.closeAdd').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using `if($('.closeAdd').css("display") == 'block')` or `hidden`

Comment: @G.Mendes That worked. Do you know if jQuery sets `display` to `block` on all `OS` and `browsers` when using show()?

Comment: yes, you can check the docs also if any trouble, http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since display is being updated you can check it in your function as it follows:

```
if(type === 'user' && action === 'add') {
   if($('.closeAdd').css("display") == 'none') {
     $('.closeAdd').show();
   }
} else { 
   if($('.closeAdd').css("display") == 'block') {
    $('.closeAdd').hide();
   }
}
```